# Only image files are showing up in my folder when I view my phone's files on the computer

Tags: samsung, internal-storage, data-recovery, file-transfer, bugs

I need to transfer some sound recordings from my Samsung Android phone to my computer, however when I view the phone's files on my computer, only image files (.jpg, .png, .bmp, etc.) are visible.

- No .mp3 files from the /sounds/ folder are appearing.
- No .mp3 files from my music albums are appearing (but the album cover photo is appearing!
- No .pdf files from my /documents/ folder are appearing.

For all three of the above bullet points, the files are clearly visible (and accessible!) if I look on the phone itself, just not on the computer.

Originally I thought this was something wrong with my Ubuntu 16.04 computer, but then I tried on a different Ubuntu 16.04 computer and still couldn't view the files, and now I've tried on Windows 10 and ***still*** can't view the files on my computer!

What can I do to transfer these files from the phone to the computer?
I do not have any memory card inserted into the phone, only internal storage.

Answer (score 2):

Set the USB Connection that pops-up on your status bar to **File Transfer** instead of Photo Transfer.

[image]